# Nginx as a proxy for tomcat with subdirectory

Tags: nginx, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I want to set up a Nginx Proxy for the Tomcat server with my domain name such as

```
example.com/demo/sample
example.com/demo/manager
example.com/demo/other_apps
...
```

Here is my Nginx `server block` configuration

```
server {
        listen   80;

        server_name example.com;

        location /demo/ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://IP_ADD_TOMCAT_SERVER:8080/;

        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

## Only allow these request methods ##
     if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
         return 444;
     }
## Do not accept DELETE, SEARCH and other methods ##

}
```

I encountered 2 problems here:

**The First Problem**:

if `TOM_CAT_INSTALL_DIR/webapps/sample/` contains a static page `hello.jsp`, it works with URL:

> example.com/demo/app1/

but not works with URL:

> example.com/demo/app1

Why I must add a trailing slash `/` at the end of URL to make the nginx proxy working?

---

**The Second Problem**:

If `TOM_CAT_INSTALL_DIR/webapps/manager` contains a `index.jsp` file which is a dynamic webpage, it does not work with URL

> example.com/demo/manager/

The URL becomes

> example.com/manager/....

Followed by a long list of parameters.

if I manually add `/demo/` string to the web browser URL, it works again.

How should I make the nginx proxy works with sub-directory `/demo/`?

**Update:** I found out the missing rewrite problem for tomcat manager subdirecotry is that in the index.jsp file, the `request.getContextPath()` will NOT automatically add /demo/ subdirecotry into the URL. It seems we have to manually modify the .jsp file code.

If you don't know how to modify the jsp code as I do, you can work around it by using the below code in Nginx

```
# Must add the trailing '/' for both location and proxy_pass
 location /demo/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://TOM_CAT_SERVER_IP_ADDR:8080/;
        }

# ONLY work for manager apps, for other apps, 
# You must add more rewrite rules like the below
        location /manager/ {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /demo/$1 last;
        }
```

Comment: if `example.com/demo/manager/` becomes `example.com/manager/` that means you have a rewrite rule there or the file itself has a rewrite rule. by the way, I don't see the root in your config settings!! you have to have a root so that the server can tell where the root is...

Comment: the tomcat server is not running on the nginx server so I couldn't possibly set the root=/path/to/tomcat on nginx server file system. Or can I?

Comment: so how do you use Tomcat with Nginx then? isn't it as a proxy? can you explain what your server structure?

Comment: Nginx is a proxy server, Tomcat is a java app server, they are on the same network with 2 IP addresses. A very simple server structure.

Comment: ok, I thought different thing. I just noticed that you found the solution to your issue, which is something you updated in your original question. glad to hear things now work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you added something `/` extra in your config settings...

Look at this line:

```
proxy_pass http://IP_ADD_TOMCAT_SERVER:8080/;
```

you need to remove the trailing slash and it should work fine.

like this:

```
proxy_pass http://IP_ADD_TOMCAT_SERVER:8080;
```

try it out and see if things go fine!!

**Update#1** I just noticed that you have another mistake "same typo" in your `location /`

**remove the 2nd slash and it should work fine!!**

like this : `location /demo {` instead of this `location /demo/ {`

**Update #1: you can test your url using this**

```
$ curl -I http://yoururl.com
```

and see what result gives you. this way you know if it is working or not.

**Update #3:**

your setting to work with any `.jsp` extension should have this code in your vhost:

```
location ~ \.jsp$ {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
  }
```

also to get `/demo` to work , you need to add rewrite code below `server_name example.com`

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /demo/$1;
```

Comment: I just updated the answer because I found out what the second issue is about!

Comment: I remove the both '/' but example.com/demo/app1 still gives me 404 error

Comment: ok, quick question, `location /demo/` is it a folder or a subdomain?

Comment: `location /demo/` does not exist as a folder, you can see it as a domain in which I also can use demo.example.com. But I want to use example.com/demo/ instead.

Comment: in this case it is a subdomain, and you need therefore to configure this subdomain so that it works either `demo.example.com` or `example.com/demo`. I will update the answer soon

Answer (score 0):

My case 
http://localhost:8080/demo  first page working but image and other components not get from server 
So I add following mapping

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  www.example.org example.org;

    #remove /demo if it come to URI otherwise it add two time for call proxy
    rewrite ^/demo(.*)$ $1;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /demo/$1;

    location / {
       proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
   }
  }
```